# Syntax error in continuous assignment

Tags: debugging, syntax, verilog

Where is the error in my code?

```
module mikroislemci(data1,data2,opcode,data_out,flag);
input [7:0] data1;
input [7:0] data2;
input [3:0] opcode;
output [7:0] data_out;
output [4:0] flag;
wire [8:0] tmp;
wire [7:0] tmp1;
 if(opcode==4'b0000)
 begin 
    if (data1==data2)
      begin
        assign flag[0]=1;
      end
    else
      begin
        assign tmp = data1+data2;
        assign data_out=tmp [7:0];
            assign flag[2]=tmp [8];
      end
 end
else if (opcode==4'b0001)
  begin
    if (data1==data2)
      begin
        assign flag[0]=1;
      end
    if(data1>data2)
      begin
            assign data_out=data1-data2;
      end
    else
      begin 
                assign data_out=data2-data1;
        assign  flag[1]=1;
      end

  end 
 else if (opcode==4'b0010)
  begin
    assign data_out[0]=data1[0] and data2[0];
    assign data_out[1]=data1[1] and data2[1];
    assign data_out[2]=data1[2] and data2[2];
    assign data_out[3]=data1[3] and data2[3];
    assign data_out[4]=data1[4] and data2[4];
    assign data_out[5]=data1[5] and data2[5];
    assign data_out[6]=data1[6] and data2[6];
    assign data_out[7]=data1[7] and data2[7];

  end
else if (opcode==4'b0011)
  begin
    assign data_out[0]=data1[0] or data2[0];
    assign data_out[1]=data1[1] or data2[1];
    assign data_out[2]=data1[2] or data2[2];
    assign data_out[3]=data1[3] or data2[3];
    assign data_out[4]=data1[4] or data2[4];
    assign data_out[5]=data1[5] or data2[5];
    assign data_out[6]=data1[6] or data2[6];
    assign data_out[7]=data1[7] or data2[7];

  end
else if (opcode==4'b0100)
  begin
    assign data_out[0]=data1[0] xor data2[0];
    assign data_out[1]=data1[1] xor data2[1];
    assign data_out[2]=data1[2] xor data2[2];
    assign data_out[3]=data1[3] xor data2[3];
    assign data_out[4]=data1[4] xor data2[4];
    assign data_out[5]=data1[5] xor data2[5];
    assign data_out[6]=data1[6] xor data2[6];
    assign data_out[7]=data1[7] xor data2[7];

  end
else if (opcode==4'b0101)
  begin
    assign data_out[0]= not(data1[0]);
    assign data_out[1]= not(data1[1]);
    assign data_out[2]= not(data1[2]);  
    assign data_out[3]= not(data1[3]);
    assign data_out[4]= not(data1[4]);
    assign data_out[5]= not(data1[5]);
    assign data_out[6]= not(data1[6]);  
    assign data_out[7]= not(data1[7]);

  end
else if (opcode==4'b0110)
  begin
    if(data1==data2)
      begin
                assign flag[0]=1;
      end
    else if(data1<data2)
      begin
        assign flag[4]=0;
      end
    else if(data1>data2)
      begin
        assign flag[4]=1;
      end

  end
else if (opcode==4'b0111)
  begin
     assign data_out=data1<<data2;
  end
else if (opcode==4'b1000)
  begin
     assign data_out=data1>>data2;
  end

 else
  display("you entered wrong opcode try again");

endmodule
```

Comment: ...What exactly is the output?

Comment: data_out is the output .if the output would be 9 bit at the adder or be minus at sub flag is can be used as cary or sign. Here is the work ı am tring to do http://web.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr/~onderefe/bbm231/2013-2014%20Guz%20Proje.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

verilog `if` statements have to go inside a process either `initial` or `always`

```
output reg [4:0] flag;

always @* begin
  if(opcode==4'b0000) begin 
    if (data1==data2) begin
      flag[0]=1;
     end
   //..
```

Do not use assign inside these processes, and do use `reg` or `logic` types. The above creates combinatorial logic.

To imply sequential (flip-flops) use:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  flag[0] <= 1'b1;
end
```

Again use `reg` or `logic` types and non-blocking assignments `<=`.

Comment: @user220910 Excellent, Verilog is not too bad once you get use to it. The [LRM (Language Reference Manual) is available free](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), not the best way to learn but good for reference.